# Postgres totals by classification per group

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, count, aggregate-functions

for example i have an orders table with a classification column. i want to get the total per classification for each city in a state for certain identified cities, for specific date.

I have done the following, which works.

```
SELECT
       state.id                                             AS state_id,
       state.name                                           AS state_name,
       city.id                                                    AS city_id,
       city.name                                                  AS city_name,
       count(*)                                                            AS total,
       count(CASE WHEN o.classification = 'A' THEN 1 END) AS total_A,
       count(CASE WHEN o.classification = 'B' THEN 1 END) AS total_B,
FROM orders AS o
         LEFT JOIN city ON o.city_id = city.id             
         LEFT JOIN state ON city.state_id = state.id
WHERE o.category = 'CATEGORY'
  AND o.city_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16)
   AND (o.trn_date::date = '2020-05-07')
GROUP BY state.id, state.name, city.id, city.name
ORDER BY state.name, city.name;
```

The problem is that i don't always get the same number (16) of cities specified in the in clause.

How can i always get 16 records even if they are all zero for some

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your join order, move the `orders` conditions to the `left join`, and use `filter` expressions on your `count()` columns.

```
SELECT state.id    AS state_id,
       state.name  AS state_name,
       city.id     AS city_id,
       city.name   AS city_name,
       count(*) FILTER (WHERE o.city_id IS NOT NULL) AS total,
       count(*) FILTER (WHERE o.classification = 'A') AS total_A,
       count(*) FILTER (WHERE o.classification = 'B') AS total_B
  FROM state 
       JOIN city on city.state_id = state.id
       LEFT JOIN orders AS o
              ON o.city_id = city.id             
             AND o.category = 'CATEGORY'
             AND o.trn_date::date = '2020-05-07'
 WHERE city.id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16)
 GROUP BY state.id, state.name, city.id, city.name
 ORDER BY state.name, city.name;
```